# Repetition of article before the same noun

Tags: definite-articles

Which phrase is more correct between:

"At high speed the increase is not relevant, while the directivity of noise pattern is significantly altered by blade re-design. On the contrary, at low speed THE directivity is not significantly modified..."

and

"At high speed the increase is not relevant, while the directivity of noise pattern is significantly altered by blade re-design. On the contrary, at low speed directivity is not significantly modified..."

Comment: It seems to me that neither the version with the THE nor the version without the THE is inherently better than the other, although the version without the THE would read more clearly with a comma after "at low speed," to avoid temporary misreadings of that phrase as modifying _directivity_.

Comment: "On the contrary" is usually used to mean "No, that's wrong, it's actually..." but here you want "conversely"

Answer (score 1):

Without a better context, the correctness of your two sentences is difficult to determine. A natural question arises: If "At high speed the increase is not relevant," *what exactly* is being increased? In other words, the increase of *what* is not relevant?

I'm assuming (perhaps wrongly) that you are talking about the increase in *noise* which the vehicle(?) makes. In other words, after the word *increase* should be the words *of noise*. Thus we have

> "At high speed the increase of noise is not relevant . . .."

If so, you have four variables:

> - speed,
> - noise,
> - directivity, and
> - blade design.

Here, then, is how the variables interact with each other:

1. As speed increases, noise increases.
2. As speed increases, the directivity of the noise is altered.
3. However, by redesigning the blade, the directivity of the noise will be lessened.
4. As speed decreases, the directivity of the noise lessens.

In conclusion, then (if my surmise is correct), your sentences should be read, (with my changes highlighted):

> "At high speed the increase **in noise** is not relevant, while the directivity of the noise pattern is significantly altered by blade re-design. On the contrary, at low speed THE directivity **of the noise** is not significantly modified . . .."

I agree with your addition of the word *the* before *directivity*.

Comment: thank you for your clarification. I've omitted the phrase coming first, which states:
"Finally, the acoustic assessment has shown that the optimal blade configuration yields higher noise emissions, thus confirming the more acoustically annoying nature of low vibratory rotors." I've tried to avoid repetitions as possible, but maybe the result is a bit misleading.